# Access SQL - UPDATE If no record exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update checkbox in record If record in table doesn't exist in another table.

Example data:

```
Table1:
111 John Davies
222 Mike Johnson
333 Allen Mckenzie

Table2:
000 John Jackson
222 Laura Kent
444 Paul Saint
```

I want to update only records, that have all fields different together, so in other words - each field doesn't exist. In my example result for this would be:

```
444 Paul Saint
```

I've tried with NOT IN, LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, but can't figure out correct clause because I need to update checkbox - so clause MUST Involve UPDATE.

Any ideas ?

Comment: would 000 John Jackson also be valid? or is this because John already exists somewhere? Can you clarify your example a bit more?

Comment: No, 000 john jackson is not valid, since John allready exists in Table1. I said that, all fields different.

Comment: So your database can only have one guy called John? Seems like a weird requirement

Comment: @JanR, It's not weird requierement. I need to track newly Imported records and have a list of new ones, with different criterias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
Update Table1
SET Checkbox = True
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM Table2
                 WHERE table1.id=table2.id 
                    OR table1.name=table2.name 
                    or table1.surname=table2.surname)
```

Comment: what if you need to update table2? because it contains the different value?

Comment: I guess the query needs to be reversed then

Comment: @JanR: it is funny that you asked. MS Access's weird UPDATE statement allows updating columns from multiple tables at the same time. It may not be applicable for this case, but Access has this feature for normally joined tables.

Comment: @cha, weirdly your solution works in Access Query builder, but not in VBA. What could be wrong ?

Comment: GOT IT !! Space bettwen one of the words was problem. Thanks for answer, exactly what I needed !!